# Hive jdbc.query(sql, rowmapper) throws UnCatogarized exception

Tags: java, spring, hadoop, hive, hiveql

I'm using `spring-jdbc template` to query `Hive-0.11.0` 
The following code does well.

```
public List<Student> listStudents() {
      String SQL = "select * from Student";
      List <Student> students = jdbcTemplateObject.query(SQL, 
                                new StudentMapper());
      return students;
   }
public class StudentMapper implements RowMapper<Student> {
   public Student mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
      Student student = new Student();
      student.setId(rs.getInt("id"));
      student.setName(rs.getString("name"));
      student.setAge(rs.getInt("age"));
      return student;
   }
}
```

Upgraded to Hive-0.14.x, and everything remains same. But the program doesn't run. Throws the following exception:

```
org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException: StatementCallback; uncategorized SQLException for SQL []; SQL state [null]; error code [0]; null; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:84)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:81)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:81)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:413)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:468)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:478)
    Caused by: java.sql.SQLException
org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveBaseResultSet.findColumn(HiveBaseResultSet.java:93)
    at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveBaseResultSet.getString(HiveBaseResultSet.java:609)
    at org.clinical3PO.model.StudentMapper.mapRow(StudentMapper.java:15)
    at org.clinical3PO.model.StudentMapper.mapRow(StudentMapper.java:8)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapperResultSetExtractor.extractData(RowMapperResultSetExtractor.java:93)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapperResultSetExtractor.extractData(RowMapperResultSetExtractor.java:60)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$1QueryStatementCallback.doInStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:457)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:402)
    ... 5 more
```

Is there's a code change from Hive-0.11.0 to Hive-0.14.x ?

Comment: org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveBaseResultSet.findColumn(HiveBaseResultSet.java:93)
 Says it cannot find one of the columns, have you changed datatype of any of them?

Comment: No, i haven't changed the datatype. I suppose findColumn() is a method of HiveVaseResultSet.java where error has occured. Isn't it ? @tom

Answer (score 1):

Hive 0.14.0 returns the column names as is, queried. To go deep into it: 
Consider 2 tables `abc` & `xyz`.
And the query is:- `SELECT abc.id, xyz.age, abc.name from db.abc JOIN ON db.xyz WHERE abc.id=xyz.id;`

ResultSet of Hive-0.11.0:

```
student.setId(rs.getInt("id"));
student.setName(rs.getString("name"));
student.setAge(rs.getInt("age"));
```

ResultSet of Hive-0.14.0:

```
student.setId(rs.getInt("abc.id"));
student.setName(rs.getString("abc.name"));
student.setAge(rs.getInt("xyz.age"));
```

This is how it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

After looking your code,I suggest below tweaks (Preference should be based on simplicity)

- Using ResultSetExtractor

  ```
  public List<Student> listStudents() {
  String sql= "select * from Student";
  List <Student> students = jdbcTemplateObject.query(sql, 
                          new ResultSetExtractor<Student>() {
  @Override
  public Student extractData(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException,
                                                 DataAccessException {
  Student student = new Student();
  if(rs.next())
  {          
   student.setId(rs.getInt("id"));
   student.setName(rs.getString("name"));
   student.setAge(rs.getInt("age"));
  }
   return student;
   else
   return null;
  }});
  return students;
  }
  ```
- Using List (Keep It Simple :-))

  ```
  List<Student> students = jdbcTemplateObject.queryForList(sql, Student.class);
  ```

Comment: Thanks @tom. I have used queryForList to figure out what went wrong. I'm still using rowmapper.